# Routing IIS - Angular - Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, routes

I'm posting this message because I didn't find any workable answer.
I'm developing a web site using Angular 6, Asp.net Core 2.2 and IIS 10.
My problem concerns the routing when directly imputing the address in the Browser url input area. Using the website, inside navigation, everything is working properly.
My website plan is:

```
/ 
--> /upload
--> /admin
----> /admin/admincreateuser
----> /admin/manageuserlicencepanel
```

Here are my settings:

**Angular 6**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'upload',
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        {path: '', component: UploadComponent, data: {roles: ['Customer']} },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        {path: '', component: AdminComponent, data: {roles: ['Admin', 'Moderator']}},
        {path: 'admincreateuser', component: AdminCreateUserComponent, data: {roles: ['Admin', 'Moderator']}},
        {path: 'manageuserlicencepanel', component: ManageUserLicencePanelComponent, data: {roles: ['Admin', 'Moderator']}}}}
    ]
  },
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

**ASP.Net Core 2.2**

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {              
        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller="FallbackController", action = "Index"}
        );
    }
}
```

**FallbackController.cs**

```
public class FallbackController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "index.html"), "text/HTML");
    }
}
```

This configuration is working properly even on IIS deployement. But it's impossible to input directly the url ( i.e https://www.dzfzx.com/upload ) in the address bar because I get a 404 error.
To solve this I've tried to add URL Rewrite in IIS like this

```
   <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rewriteMaps>
              <rewriteMap name="^(.*)$" />
            </rewriteMaps>
            <rules>
                <rule name="All routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/api(.*)$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^api/" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

By implementing that I get directly on home page an error:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*

Notice also that it seems I never fallback in my FallbackController which seems to be not normal.

**Have you an idea on how I can make it work ( Direct address bar inputing ) ?**

Thanks.

Comment: Check this solution, https://medium.com/@h.alhaj/angular-route-with-iis-shared-host-d8dfc80877c4

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your configuration is bad. You should direct all requests to `index.html`, which is angular's index file.

Try this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

[Deploy an Angular Application to IIS](https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7)

Comment: That doesn't work. Same error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

Comment: For me the role of the FallbackController is to redirect to the Angular index.html, that's why I was redirecting to "/".

Comment: Where do you see this error? In the browser console?

Comment: Yes in Browser console, and nothing appears on the page.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with the fact that it serves index.html even when the browser is requesting the javascript files ( runtime.js, main.js, etc... )

Comment: MOst probably you have an error in your html templates. Also, you can open source code of the and try to open all JS files and see if these files are loading in your browser. Or you can do it in dev console.